# Check a box based on the current url

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, accordion

There is a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't find a solution so here goes. I am making a custom wordpress theme, and I have an accordion in the sidebar that is a menu. The expanding of a list is triggered by a checkbox.

```
<div>
    <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-1">Menu category 1</label>
    <ul>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-1">List item 1</a></li>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-2">List item 2</a></li>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-3">List item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-2">Menu category 2</label>
    <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-4">List item 4</a></li>
    <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-5">List item 5</a></li>
    <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-6">List item 6</a></li>
</div>
```

It all works well, even on mobile phones and tablets, but the problem is that whenever a visitor changes a page, any checked option will be cleared. What I wish to achieve is the following: If a user is on list item #1 page, the parent checkbox would be checked (in this case, Menu category 1 would be expanded on page load), since the page belongs to that category. I need a way to check a certain box based on the current url. I found an option to cache the sidebar with AJAX but that really does not work for me, because if all the items were expanded on a previous page, they would remain the same on a new page, and I want only the relevant parent to be expanded. Also, the cache thing looks like an overkill. I found a php shortcode to preserve the marks on refresh,

```
<?php if($_POST['check'] == 'checked'): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
```

but that doesn't work on url change, only refresh.

Bare in mind that I use a php menu shortcode for WP, and not static ul li as shown in this question. I'm developing locally so I can't provide a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer but a workable solution. I've used jQuery as I've assumed you are probably using it, as most accordions these days are built with jQuery plugins.

You could add hashes to the URL that correspond to the checkbox ID:

```
<div>
    <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-1">Menu category 1</label>
    <ul>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-1#ac-1">List item 1</a></li>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-2#ac-1">List item 2</a></li>
        <li class="ac-small first"><a href="li-3#ac-1">List item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Grab the hash from the URL, find the corresponding checkbox with the same ID and trigger a click and check it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash; // for example ac-1
    if (hash) {
        $('#'+hash).prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
    }
});
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pSZ39/1/) demo. I made a basic accordion menu and faked a URL hash to make it work.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

As requested, it's pretty simple doing it for the URL. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get url
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    // get part of url after last slash
    var accordionID = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    // trigger a click on checkbox representing that accordion li
    $('a[href="'+accordionID+'"]').closest('div').find(':checkbox')
        .prop('checked',true).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

[See the demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/pSZ39/2/)

Comment: Thaks, I will give it a shot and report back :)

Comment: I actualy have a problem since I use pretty links in WP, so I can't add a #. But I have a better idea. Can I compare url and link in the li? So if the current url is example.com/page-1/, and have a link in the menu /page-1/ to check the box. I think that it can be done, I just don't have enough knowlege of jQuery to do it. Could you give me hand? I've done some research, but I can't get it to work. I found something similar [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)

Comment: @user3026261, have a look at my updated answer. I've provided a way to use URL's.

Comment: it works great, thank you very much! I hope will be of some help to you someday